# Jquery validation in webform

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched in net for text box validation where i have found so many jquery functions, i choosed a one and implemented and there the real problem began , it is not that much easy to implement first jquery plugin i think,,

```
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


</head>
  <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<h3 style="color:Olive">
ADD NEW USER BELOW
</h3>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdField" runat="server" />
</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td style= " font-size:large">
            Name:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
           .

           |
           |
           |
           <tr>
         <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="46px" 
                OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel"                         OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and after the table design just before the  tag i placed my jquery scripts which are:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function({
            $("#form1").validate({
                 rules:{
        <%=txtName.UniqueID%>:{
            required:true}
                   },
               messages:{
         <%=txtName.UniqueID%>:{
         required:"This field is required"}

                   } 
                  });

               });

       </script>
             <script type="text/javascript">

             jQuery.validator.setDefaults({

             debug: true,

              success: "valid"

         }); ;

      </script>
```

please anybody help me

Comment: What is the problem, can't you go further or are you getting an error?

Comment: validation is not taking place!!! I do not getting the message 'this field required' if i left the text box empty!!

Comment: that's a very old version of jQuery you're including there

Comment: Instead of $('#form1').validate(), try $('form') and let me know what happens please

Comment: oh sorry!!! i forgot to give open and close braces after 'function()' its working now!!